# Print alternating lines with conditional

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep

Still struggling with messy logfiles. What I want is to find lines that first matching string X and then string Y. I then want to print them together. The problem is that, sometimes there is X, but no Y.

**Example input**

```
31 X
32 Y
33 X
34 Y
35 X
36 X
37 Y
38 X
39 X
```

**Expected output**

```
31 X
32 Y
33 X
34 Y
36 X
37 Y
```

So, lines 35, 38 and 39 are omitted because there is no string Y.

My starting is point is this:

```
cat $filename | grep -E X\|Y | grep -A1 'X'
```

But this does not filter out lines 35, 38 and 39. What I want is a conditional: only print the lines X and then Y if there is Y. If not, print nothing.

Comment: Add `|uniq -f1` to your pipeline.

Comment: `uniq` can read files as well.  `uniq -f1 filename`  will work just fine

Comment: @val0x00ff - well, not exactly, unless the only lines in file are X/Y lines. `grep` or something is till required, and is probably the faster of the filters, and so should go first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you only want lines containing X if they are then followed by a line containing Y, and then you want both lines.

`grep -A1 X filename |grep --no-group-separator -B1 Y`

Comment: This does exactly what I want, and I can see why.

Answer (score 4):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n ':b /X/ { h; n; /Y/! b b; H; x; p; }'
```

Output:

```
31 X
32 Y
33 X
34 Y
36 X
37 Y
```

Comment: Thanks, I always thought about branching with sed but never used it. Finally I got an example to work with.

Comment: +, though you could do without the branching: `sed '/Y/!{h;d};//{x;/X/!d;G}' infile`

Answer (score 3):

There are various tools that can do this. If you have `pcregrep` (it should be available in your distribution's repository), you can do:

```
$ pcregrep -M 'X\n[^\n]+Y' file 
31 X
32 Y
33 X
34 Y
36 X
37 Y
```

The `-M` switch allows pattern to match across newline characters and the regular expression matches an `X`, followed by a newline, then any non-newline characters and a `Y`.

---

Another option is to write a little script that saves the previous line if it matches `X` and prints it along with the current one if the current line matches `Y`. For example, in `awk`:

```
$ awk '{if(last~/X/ && /Y/){print last"\n"$0}last=$0}' file 
31 X
32 Y
33 X
34 Y
36 X
37 Y
```

Or Perl:

```
$ perl -ne '$last=~/X/ && /Y/ && print "$last$_"; $last=$_' file 
31 X
32 Y
33 X
34 Y
36 X
37 Y
```

Answer (score 3):

Another `sed`:

```
$ sed -e '/X/{
    $!N
    /\n.*Y/!D
}' file
31 X
32 Y
33 X
34 Y
36 X
37 Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question was tagged with `awk`:

```
$ awk 'p2 == "X" && $2 == "Y" { print p; print } { p = $0; p2 = $2 }' file
31 X
32 Y
33 X
34 Y
36 X
37 Y
```

This prints an `X` line and the immediately following `Y` line, if there is one (or neither of them would be printed).

The variables `p` and `p2` holds the unmodified previous line and its second column respectively.